# java.rmi.RemoteException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is:

Tags: java, ejb

I am inputting information into a database and I am having some EJB Exception. The path of info is going from A JSP with an action class, which inserts values into a remote EJB method which inter(within that method) calls another method to access hibernate, which then calls another method to insert into the DB. I have used this method or way of insertion on an outside application and it works fine. though when trying to integrate it with an Enterprise Level application I'm running into these problems. It says that

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/multivision/cis/business/classes/DaoAccessor`

when my `DaoAccessor` class is "clearly" defined in my project's build path pointing to the appropriate jar, as well as in my `Web-INF/lib` folder. I have no idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. Not all application servers (alteast older versions) support EJB deployment in WAR file. Check what JSR 220 talks about it. You might want to deploy your EJBs separately (jar in EAR) and try it out

Comment: I exported it as reg Jar file and I not loaded it to the server as well as placing it in an ear project and loading that to the server. I also am using Weblogic Server 11g patchSet4 which i believe is the newsest one?. I don't understand why it works fine with my outside jsp's and integrating but as soon as i try to integrate to an enterprise size application it goes all screwey.